(SSJS Cloudpage Error while batching records) Fetching Records: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame
I have a cloudpage which serves the purpose of ejecting records from existing journey(s). The credentials are stored in a BU Package DE, so are the records in an ejection DE. Since the exit contact api has a limit of 50 records per call, I am trying to batch it.
For some reason I am getting the Error Fetching Records: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame while batching records error when I first tried batching in small quantities(just 2 records per batch)
I have been trying to figure out for the whole day what is causing this but am unable to come to a conclusion. I wrote a lot of log statements but still am unable to figure out whats causing this error
[UPDATE] I am getting a new error:
Updated Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Response Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Response</h1>
        <div>
            %%[
                SET @rows = LookupRows("BU_PACKAGE_DETAILS_DE", "ACCOUNT_MID", "100029102")
                IF RowCount(@rows) > 0 THEN
                    SET @clientId = Field(Row(@rows, 1), "CLIENT_ID")
                    SET @clientSecret = Field(Row(@rows, 1), "CLIENT_SECRET")
                    SET @accountId = Field(Row(@rows, 1), "ACCOUNT_MID")
                ELSE
                    SET @clientId = "Not Found"
                    SET @clientSecret = "Not Found"
                    SET @accountId = "Not Found"
                ENDIF
            ]%%

            <script runat="server">
                Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

                var clientId = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@clientId");
                var clientSecret = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@clientSecret");
                var accountId = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@accountId");

                var batchSize = 2; // Process records in batches of 2
                var batchNumber = 1;
                var continueProcessing = true;

                try {
                    // Step 1: Retrieve Access Token
                    Write("Step 1: Retrieving Access Token<br>");
                    var accessToken = getAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, accountId);
                    if (!accessToken) {
                        throw new Error("Access token not retrieved");
                    }
                    Write("Access Token: " + accessToken + "<br>");
                    
                    while (continueProcessing) {
                        Write("Entering while loop for batch number: " + batchNumber + "<br>");
                        
                        try {
                            // Step 2: Fetch records from Data Extension
                            Write("Step 2: Fetching records from Data Extension<br>");
                            var records = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows("EJECTION_DE", batchSize, "RANK ASC", "PROCESSED_STATUS", "false");
                            Write("Records Retrieved: " + Platform.Function.Stringify(records) + "<br>");
                            
                            if (records && records.length > 0) {
                                var payload = [];
                                for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                                    var record = records[i];
                                    var contactKey = record.PATIENT_COMPOSITE_KEY;
                                    var journeyDefinitionKey = record.JOURNEY_DEFINITION_KEY;
                                    Write("Processing Record " + i + ": ContactKey - " + contactKey + ", DefinitionKey - " + journeyDefinitionKey + "<br>");
                                    
                                    payload.push({
                                        "ContactKey": contactKey,
                                        "DefinitionKey": journeyDefinitionKey
                                    });
                                }

                                Write("Batch Number: " + batchNumber + "<br>");
                                Write("Payload: " + Platform.Function.Stringify(payload) + "<br>");

                                var response = makeApiCall(accessToken, payload);
                                Write("API Call Response Status Code: " + (response ? response.statusCode : "No Response") + "<br>");
                                Write("API Call Response: " + Platform.Function.Stringify(response) + "<br>");

                                if (response && (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 202)) {
                                    Write("API call to exit contacts from journey was successful.<br>");
                                    for (var j = 0; j < records.length; j++) {
                                        var updateRecord = records[j];
                                        Write("Updating Record " + j + ": Rank - " + updateRecord.RANK + "<br>");
                                        var updateStatus = Platform.Function.UpdateData("EJECTION_DE", ["RANK"], [updateRecord.RANK], ["PROCESSED_STATUS", "TEST_RESPONSE_STATUS", "TEST_BATCH_NUMBER"], ["true", response.statusCode, batchNumber]);
                                        Write("Update Status: " + updateStatus + "<br>");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Write("Failed to exit contacts from journey. Status Code: " + (response ? response.statusCode : "No Response") + "<br>");
                                }

                                batchNumber++;
                            } else {
                                continueProcessing = false;
                                Write("No more records to process.<br>");
                            }
                        } catch (fetchError) {
                            Write("Error Fetching Records: " + fetchError.message + "<br>");
                            Write("Stack Trace: " + fetchError.stack + "<br>");
                            continueProcessing = false;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ex) {
                    Write("Error: " + ex.message + "<br>");
                    Write("Stack Trace: " + ex.stack + "<br>");
                }

                function getAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, accountId) {
                    try {
                        var authEndpoint = "https://REDACTED.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
                        var authPayload = Platform.Function.Stringify({
                            grant_type: "client_credentials",
                            client_id: clientId,
                            client_secret: clientSecret,
                            account_id: accountId
                        });

                        var authResponse = HTTP.Post(authEndpoint, "application/json", authPayload);
                        Write("Auth Response: " + authResponse.StatusCode + "<br>");
                        if (authResponse.StatusCode === 200) {
                            var authData = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(authResponse.Response[0]);
                            return authData.access_token;
                        } else {
                            throw new Error("Failed to retrieve access token. Status Code: " + authResponse.StatusCode);
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        Write("Error in getAccessToken: " + e.message + "<br>");
                        Write("Stack Trace: " + e.stack + "<br>");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                function makeApiCall(accessToken, payload) {
                    try {
                        var endpointUrl = "https://REDACTED.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/contactexit";
                        var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(endpointUrl);
                        req.retries = 3;
                        req.continueOnError = true;

                        req.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                        req.method = "POST";
                        req.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                        req.postData = Platform.Function.Stringify(payload);

                        Write("Sending API Request...<br>");
                        var response = req.send();

                        if (response) {
                            Write("API Response Status Code: " + response.statusCode + "<br>");
                            Write("API Response Content: " + response.content + "<br>");
                        } else {
                            Write("No response from API call.<br>");
                        }

                        if (response.contentType === "application/json") {
                            return Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.content);
                        } else {
                            return response.content;
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        Write("Error in makeApiCall: " + e.message + "<br>");
                        Write("Stack Trace: " + e.stack + "<br>");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

UPDATED ERROR OUTPUT:
Step 1: Retrieving Access Token
Auth Response: 200
Access Token: REDACTED
Step 2: Fetching records from Data Extension
Records Retrieved: [{"_CustomObjectKey":114,"RANK":1",CreatedDate":"2024-06-12T05:20:20.600","TEST_RESPONSE_STATUS":"","TEST_BATCH_NUMBER":""}, 
{"SIMILARLY SECOND RECORD}]
Error Fetching Records: Use of Common Language Runtime (CLR) is not allowed
Stack Trace: undefined

ARCHIVED OLD code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Response Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Response
    <div class="layout layout-canvas-g">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="columns col1">
                <div data-type="slot" data-key="col1">
                    %%[
                        SET @rows = LookupRows("BU_PACKAGE_DETAILS_DE", "ACCOUNT_MID", "100029102")
                        IF RowCount(@rows) > 0 THEN
                            SET @clientId = Field(Row(@rows, 1), "CLIENT_ID")
                            SET @clientSecret = Field(Row(@rows, 1), "CLIENT_SECRET")
                            SET @accountId = Field(Row(@rows, 1), "ACCOUNT_MID")
                        ELSE
                            SET @clientId = "Not Found"
                            SET @clientSecret = "Not Found"
                            SET @accountId = "Not Found"
                        ENDIF
                    ]%%
                    <script runat="server">
                        Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

                        var clientId = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@clientId");
                        var clientSecret = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@clientSecret");
                        var accountId = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@accountId");

                        var batchSize = 2; // Process records in batches of 2
                        var batchNumber = 1;
                        var continueProcessing = true;

                        try {
                            // Step 1: Retrieve Access Token
                            Write("Step 1: Retrieving Access Token<br>");
                            var accessToken = getAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, accountId);
                            if (!accessToken) {
                                throw new Error("Access token not retrieved");
                            }
                            Write("Access Token: " + accessToken + "<br>");
                            
                            while (continueProcessing) {
                                // Step 2: Fetch records from Data Extension
                                Write("Step 2: Fetching records from Data Extension<br>");
                                try {
                                    var records = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows("EJECTION_DE", batchSize, "RANK ASC", "PROCESSED_STATUS", "false");
                                    Write("Records Retrieved: " + Platform.Function.Stringify(records) + "<br>");
                                    
                                    if (Platform.Function.RowCount(records) > 0) {
                                        var payload = [];
                                        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                                            var record = records[i];
                                            var contactKey = record.PATIENT_COMPOSITE_KEY;
                                            var journeyDefinitionKey = record.JOURNEY_DEFINITION_KEY;

                                            payload.push({
                                                "ContactKey": contactKey,
                                                "DefinitionKey": journeyDefinitionKey
                                            });
                                        }

                                        // Log the payload to ensure it is correctly formatted
                                        Write("Batch Number: " + batchNumber + "<br>");
                                        Write("Payload: " + Platform.Function.Stringify(payload) + "<br>");

                                        var response = makeApiCall(accessToken, payload);
                                        Write("API Call Response: " + Platform.Function.Stringify(response) + "<br>");

                                        if (response && (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 202)) {
                                            Write("API call to exit contacts from journey was successful.<br>");
                                            for (var j = 0; j < records.length; j++) {
                                                var updateRecord = records[j];
                                                Platform.Function.UpdateData("EJECTION_DE", ["RANK"], [updateRecord.RANK], ["PROCESSED_STATUS", "TEST_RESPONSE_STATUS", "TEST_BATCH_NUMBER"], ["true", response.statusCode, batchNumber]);
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            Write("Failed to exit contacts from journey. Status Code: " + (response ? response.statusCode : "No Response") + "<br>");
                                        }

                                        batchNumber++;
                                    } else {
                                        continueProcessing = false;
                                        Write("No more records to process.<br>");
                                    }
                                } catch (fetchError) {
                                    Write("Error Fetching Records: " + fetchError.message + "<br>");
                                    Write("Stack Trace: " + fetchError.stack + "<br>");
                                    continueProcessing = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (ex) {
                            Write("Error: " + ex.message + "<br>");
                            Write("Stack Trace: " + ex.stack + "<br>");
                        }

                        function getAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, accountId) {
                            try {
                                var authEndpoint = "https://SFMC URL.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
                                var authPayload = Platform.Function.Stringify({
                                    grant_type: "client_credentials",
                                    client_id: clientId,
                                    client_secret: clientSecret,
                                    account_id: accountId
                                });

                                var authResponse = HTTP.Post(authEndpoint, "application/json", authPayload);
                                Write("Auth Response: " + authResponse.StatusCode + "<br>");
                                if (authResponse.StatusCode === 200) {
                                    var authData = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(authResponse.Response[0]);
                                    return authData.access_token;
                                } else {
                                    throw new Error("Failed to retrieve access token. Status Code: " + authResponse.StatusCode);
                                }
                            } catch (e) {
                                Write("Error in getAccessToken: " + e.message + "<br>");
                                Write("Stack Trace: " + e.stack + "<br>");
                                return null;
                            }
                        }

                        function makeApiCall(accessToken, payload) {
                            try {
                                var endpointUrl = "https://SFMC URL.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/contactexit";
                                var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(endpointUrl);
                                req.retries = 3;
                                req.continueOnError = true;

                                req.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                                req.method = "POST";
                                req.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                                req.postData = Platform.Function.Stringify(payload);

                                var response = req.send();
                                if (response.contentType === "application/json") {
                                    return Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.content);
                                } else {
                                    return response.content;
                                }
                            } catch (e) {
                                Write("Error in makeApiCall: " + e.message + "<br>");
                                Write("Stack Trace: " + e.stack + "<br>");
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Here is the output response:
Step 1: Retrieving Access Token
Auth Response: 200
Access Token: REDACTED
Step 2: Fetching records from Data Extension
Records Retrieved: [{"_CustomObjectKey":114,"RANK":1",CreatedDate":"2024-06-12T05:20:20.600","TEST_RESPONSE_STATUS":"","TEST_BATCH_NUMBER":""}, 
{"SIMILARLY SECOND RECORD}]
Error Fetching Records: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.
Stack Trace: undefined

NOTE: The code seems to work when I hardcode one record for ejection
PLEASE HELP ME OUT!

From your error output, the error must be within
while (continueProcessing) {
after this line (which logs)
Write("Records Retrieved: " + Platform.Function.Stringify(records) + "<br>");

and before this line (which does not log)
 Write("Batch Number: " + batchNumber + "<br>");

So really not a ton of code to go through.
Just inch forward and use "Writes" at every step.
First measure:
Add further defensive measures to your lookupOrderedRows - use this pattern;
if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) 

from here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformDataExtensionLookupOrderedRows.html
Currently you have this:
if (Platform.Function.RowCount(records) > 0) {

And I have never seen this applied. I wouldnt trust it.
Just use standard SSJS as seen above;
If that doesnt change it, rinse and repeat, just add one line and a "Write" and you can isolate this down to the erroneous piece quickly.

Thanks for the insights, I tried and got a new error this time, it says: Error Fetching Records: Use of Common Language Runtime (CLR) is not allowed after the first batch of two records is passed

I have pasted the updated code and error output in the question description too, any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

I'm serious - plaster it with write(). You can isolate this way better than we can do from the outside. Just every second line, add a debug statement. You'll have it tracked down to the row in no time, and then it gets way easier.

I'm quite done with SSJS, is there a way I can pass the response from SSJS and Use AMPscript to update the Data Extension. I wrote a lot of write commands and realised the update function is failing for some reason : (  This is even after removing the batching logic

yes possible; but failing updates can come from the data / constraints in the target DE like Primary keys, required fields, max length.
So reworking this to AMPscript probably wont do much except add more overhead.
https://sfmarketing.cloud/2022/09/06/passing-variable-values-between-ampscript-server-side-javascript-and-client-side-javascript/
